# How to join multiple sub queries as a single one without 'with'?

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

I have a query consisting of multiple subqueries. I used 'join' as im not allowed to use 'with'. The subqueries have 'from' clause which is creating an issue.

I have to display two columns with each column consisting certain logic to be displayed. For printing the two columns, i need to use sub queries which requires 'from' clause. I'm not sure how to write the 'from' clause to fit the whole query and make it runnable. I have checked the individual queries and they all work fine.

```
select lead(dt) over 
(partition by t1.id_user order by f.topup_date desc rows between 0 
preceding and unbounded following )
from 
  (select *,    
  (max(case when f.topup_value >= 20 then f.topup_date  end) over (partition 
   by f.id_user order by f.topup_date desc rows between 0 preceding and 
   unbounded following )) as dt 
   from topups f) as f, //(<-I think this is incorrect) 

CAST(f.topup_value as float)/CAST(t1.topup_value as float) from 
(SELECT t1.seq,t1.id_user,t1.topup_value,row_number() 
over (partition by t1.id_user order by t1.topup_date ) 
as rowrank from topups t1) as t1 
inner join topups f on f.id_user=t1.id_user 
inner join topups t2 on t1.seq=t2.seq
```

Comment: If the "individual queries" work, can you post them and some sample data, as well as the expected output? Why can't you use `WITH`?

Answer (score 0):

Really hard to read that query. What you marked as possible incorrectness is wrong because you're trying to add what looks like another `SELECT` after your original `FROM` clause. That's incorrect syntax. Think of your `FROM` subquery as a temporary table. You couldn't say something like:

```
SELECT some_column
FROM a_table, some_other_column
```

That's cross-join syntax. `some_other_column` would need to be a table for that to even be valid.

Consider adding a `CREATE TABLE` and sample data so we can test.

You might be looking for something along the lines of this:

```
SELECT  LEAD(temp.dt) OVER(PARTITION BY temp.id_user ORDER BY temp.topup_date DESC ROWS BETWEEN 0 PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
        , temp.division
FROM
(
    SELECT  (max(CASE WHEN f.topup_value >= 20 THEN f.topup_date  END) OVER(PARTITION BY f.id_user ORDER BY f.topup_date DESC ROWS BETWEEN 0 PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING )) AS dt
            , f.topup_value::float / t1.topup_value::float AS division
            , t1.id_user
            , f.topup_date
    FROM topups t1
        JOIN topups f USING (id_user)
) temp
;
```

Just an opinion but its less noisy to use the `::` operator to cast variables. Instead of `CAST(f.topup_value as float)` just use `f.topup_value::float`

Comment: There's an error at the 3rd 'FROM' clause , i'm back to square one

Comment: It's really hard to tell what you're trying to achieve here. With sample data and a sample table to work on we could try to test. What's the error?

Comment: Its a syntax error. Im sorry it is so confusing. These are just two subqueries which display two columns. I need to write it as a single query but as I said im not able to , because of too many 'FROM'

Comment: I forgot a set of parentheses around the sub-`SELECT`. Edited the answer

Comment: This returns the " more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression" error which leads to the alternative of joins. I'm stuck :(

Comment: The two columns you need are `LEAD ...` and the result of the division?

Comment: Yes, lead and the result of the division

Comment: You have another `JOIN` in your original query that you never use also. But I tried to simplify the query to achieve what you want but again, can't test it without any samples.

Comment: This wont work, as the below code was necesaary in the logic of both the columns. I can send you the sample and related queries to set it up if u want

Comment: If you want a copy and paste answer, you need to do some work for us. Like setup sample tables, sample input, and expected output. Add that information to your question. What logic did I remove? The only thing I thought I removed was the `JOIN` aliased as `t2`, `t2` was never used in your original query.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting a syntax error because a query can only have a single FROM clause.  It's difficult to tell the outcome you're trying to achieve, but turning the first query into a non-correlated subquery and using it for column f might be what you're looking for:

```
select
    (select lead(dt) over (partition by t1.id_user order by f.topup_date desc rows between 0 preceding and unbounded following )
    from (
        select *,    
            (max(case when f.topup_value >= 20 then f.topup_date  end) over (partition by f.id_user order by f.topup_date desc rows between 0 preceding and unbounded following )) as dt 
        from topups f
    ) x) as f,
    CAST(f.topup_value as float)/CAST(t1.topup_value as float) 
    from (
        SELECT t1.seq, t1.id_user, t1.topup_value, row_number() over (partition by t1.id_user order by t1.topup_date ) as rowrank 
        from topups t1
    ) as t1 
    inner join topups f on f.id_user=t1.id_user 
    inner join topups t2 on t1.seq=t2.seq
```

Comment: This returns the " more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression" error which leads to the alternative of joins. I'm stuck :(

Comment: it's because the query being used to get column f returns more than one value.  it won't be possible to come up w/ the proper solution without 1. the data set, and 2. the aim of the query